# Cocoa: Create draggable zones

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview

How can I create draggable zones in cocoa and be able to drag and drop images between the two.

Ex:

Zone 1:no image

Zone 2:image

drag zone 2's image to zone 1, and be able to save (core data) the location of the image.

Would I have to do something like this: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've answered your own question. You need to implement the various protocols that are described in the documentation you referenced.

You could just use two `NSImageView` objects and make them editable. Editable `NSImageView` objects allow drag and drop by default.

However, `NSImageView` doesn't store information about the location of the image in the file system. If you need that information you would need to implement your own view/control.